# spark delta overwrite a specific partition

Tags: apache-spark, delta-lake

So I have a dataframe which has a column, file_date. For a given run, the dataframe has only data for one unique file_date. For instance, in a run, let us assume that there are say about 100 records with a file_date of 2020_01_21.

I am writing this data using the following

```py
(df
 .repartition(1)
 .write
 .format("delta")
 .partitionBy("FILE_DATE")
 .mode("overwrite")
 .option("overwriteSchema", "true")
 .option("replaceWhere","FILE_DATE=" + run_for_file_date)
 .mode("overwrite")
 .save("/mnt/starsdetails/starsGrantedDetails/"))
```

My requirement is to create a folder/partition for every FILE_DATE as there is a good chance that data for a specific file_date will be rerun and the specific file_date’s data has to be overwritten. Unfortunately in the above code, if I don’t place the “replaceWhere” option, it just overwrites data for other partitions too but if I write the above, data seems to be overwriting correctly the specific partition but every time the write is done, I am getting the following error.

Please note I have also set the following spark config before the write:

```py
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")
```

But I am still getting the following error:

```
AnalysisException: "Data written out does not match replaceWhere 'FILE_DATE=2020-01-19'.\nInvalid data would be written to partitions FILE_DATE=2020-01-20.;"
```

---

Can you kindly help please.

Comment: same issue here

Comment: samuel liew - Not sure why my comment was deleted..pls let me know

Comment: did you get the solution for this? pls let me know

Comment: spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic") work for only parquet table.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are couple of things that need to be in mind while using `replaceWhere`to overwrite delta partition.
Your dataframe must be filtered before writing into partitions for example we have dataframe **DF**:

[image]

When We write this dataframe into delta table then dataframe partition coulmn range must be filtered which means we should only have partition column values within our replaceWhere condition range.

```
 DF.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").option("replaceWhere",  "date >= '2020-12-14' AND date <= '2020-12-15' ").save( "Your location")
```

if we use condition date < '2020-12-15' instead of date <= '2020-12-15' it will give us error:

[image]

Other thing is partition column value needed in quotation '2020-12-15' otherwise chances are it will give error.

There is also pull request open for delta overwrite partition`spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")` here https://github.com/delta-io/delta/pull/371 not sure if they are planning to introduce it.

Comment: This should be marked as right answer. Thanks Ali

Comment: Any idea why does this only work on Scala ? In PySpark it soesnt have the same behaviour

Comment: I am using PySpark and working same way as it works in scala.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same and realized, my dataframe had more values for the column that I tried to replace partition with.
You must filter your dataframe first and preapare your replaceWhere and write.

Answer (score 0):

What's is the specific use of ReplaceWhere here? The thing which you are trying to achieve can be simply done by setting ("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic"). It will replace existing partition if there and add new partition if it's not already there. Correct me if I am having wrong understanding.