# Would 'replaceWhere' causes deletion?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

In this command([taken from](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-batch.html)) would `replaceWhere` cause deletion of records?
eg: the date ranged mentioned in the command had 1000 rows. New df has only 100. Would this cause a deletion of 900 records?

```
df.write \
  .format("delta") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("replaceWhere", "date >= '2017-01-01' AND date <= '2017-01-31'") \
  .save("/mnt/delta/events")
```

Comment: Same question answered here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851167/spark-delta-overwrite-a-specific-partition/65305467#65305467

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This option works almost like a dynamic overwrite partition, basically you are telling Spark to overwrite only the data that is on those range partitions. In addition, data will be saved only if your dataframe matches the condition `replaceWhere`, otherwise, if a single row does not match, an exception `Data written out does not match replaceWhere` will be thrown.

```
Q: Would this cause a deletion of 900 records?
A: Yes, it would delete.
```

I did a test creating one dataframe with 2 columns

```
root
 |-- number: long (nullable = true)
 |-- even: integer (nullable = true)
```

The first run will save 1000 rows, where 500 are even and 500 are odd:

```py
rows = [Row(number=i) for i in range(0, 1000)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(rows)
df = df.withColumn('even', (f.col('number') % 2 == f.lit(0)).cast('int'))

(df
 .write
 .partitionBy('even')
 .format('delta')
 .saveAsTable('my_delta_table'))
```

[image: first dataframe output]

The second run will filter only even rows and overwrite partition where `even=1`:

```py
rows = [Row(number=i) for i in range(0, 10)]

df_only_even = spark.createDataFrame(rows)
df_only_even = df_only_even.withColumn('even', (f.col('number') % 2 == f.lit(0)).cast('int'))

# It is required to filter your dataframe or will throw an error during write operation
df_only_even = df_only_even.where(f.col('even') == f.lit(1))

(df_only_even
 .write
 .partitionBy('even')
 .format('delta')
 .option('replaceWhere', 'even == 1')
 .mode('overwrite')
 .saveAsTable('my_delta_table'))
```

[image: second dataframe output]

## Result

My table named `my_delta_table` has 505 rows, where 500 are odd and 5 are even:

[image: final table result]

Comment: Here's my link where I took the test: https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/2012413774589224/2923545371365447/476673152156399/latest.html

Comment: "Would this cause a deletion of 900 records?" What you think the answer will be?

Comment: @BlueClouds I did everything and forgot to answer directly. Yes, it would delete.